# Woes of Safari's Javascript with document.write

Tags: javascript, html, dom, safari

My problem only happens on Safari. IE, FF, Chrome and Opera all work flawlessly. I am adding an object to the DOM (exactly the same way YouTube does it, depending on ActiveX or NPAPI) so after I determine the write object type I add it to the DOM via :

`document.write(MyObject)`

At the head section of the page, so that js functions called from body can access it. It works on everything except Safari. The only way I can let Safari work is by adding an alert after document.write! I even tried setTimeout, but it works one time and fails 10.

Comment: Don't use `document.write` its horrid.

Comment: Yes, I managed to find a nice solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Document.write doesn't work correctly in the body itself, and document.body.appendChild to add an object tag doesn't work.

So what I did was

```
var objectContainer = createElement("div");
objectContainer.innerHTML = "<object blah blah> <\/object>"; //<--notice the escaping of /
document.body.appendChild(objectContainer);
```

And now it works everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using `document.body.appendChild(MyObject)`?

Comment: Already tried it. Doesn't work, but it returns a different error, which is: Can't find variable objectID

Comment: Try adding `document.write(MyObject)` to the body